# How to make a copy of a reference? (lifetime issues)

Tags: reference, rust, lifetime

I have 2 vectors (of `Result`s) inside an object. the first vector, `all_results`, owns its content, and the second vector, `current_results` contains references
to `all_results`'s content. Here's the code

```
struct Result {
    val: int
}

struct Obj<'a> {
    all_results: Vec<Result>,
    current_results: Vec<&'a mut Result>
}

impl<'a> Obj<'a> {
    fn change_something (&'a mut self) -> &[&'a mut Result] {
        let mut newVec: Vec<&'a mut Result> = Vec::new();
        for item in self.current_results.mut_iter() { 
            // type of item is &mut &'a mut Result
            item.val += 1;
            //need to create valid reference here
            if (item.val == 1) {
                newVec.push(*item); //dereferenced item is now &'a mut Result
            }
        }
        self.current_results = newVec;
        self.current_results.as_slice()
    }
}

fn main () {
    let a = Result { val: 0 };
    let b = Result { val: 1 };
    let mut obj = Obj { all_results: vec![], current_results: vec![] };
    obj.all_results.push(a);
    obj.all_results.push(b);
    obj.change_something();
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to go through each entry in `current_results`, modify the `Result` they point to, then filter the entries based on some criteria.
However, I am unable to use the same reference as the compiler complains about `item` living longer than its scope allows.

```
iter_lifetime2.rs:16:29: 16:34 error: lifetime of `item` is too short to guarantee its contents can be safely reborrowed
iter_lifetime2.rs:16                 newVec.push(*item);
                                                 ^~~~~
iter_lifetime2.rs:11:61: 21:6 note: `item` would have to be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 11:60...
iter_lifetime2.rs:11     fn change_something (&'a mut self) -> &[&'a mut Result] {
iter_lifetime2.rs:12         let mut newVec: Vec<&'a mut Result> = Vec::new();
iter_lifetime2.rs:13         for item in self.current_results.mut_iter() {
iter_lifetime2.rs:14             item.val += 1;
iter_lifetime2.rs:15             if (item.val == 1) {
iter_lifetime2.rs:16                 newVec.push(*item);
                     ...
iter_lifetime2.rs:13:9: 19:13 note: ...but `item` is only valid for the expression at 13:8
iter_lifetime2.rs:13         for item in self.current_results.mut_iter() {
iter_lifetime2.rs:14             item.val += 1;
iter_lifetime2.rs:15             if (item.val == 1) {
iter_lifetime2.rs:16                 newVec.push(*item);
iter_lifetime2.rs:17             }
iter_lifetime2.rs:18         }
```

I've tried several variants such as:

```
for item in self.current_results.mut_iter() {
    let p: &'a mut Result = *item;
    item.val += 1;
    if (item.val == 1) {
        newVec.push(p);
    }
}
```

but I get the same error regarding lifetime of `item`

Here's a basic pointer diagram of my vectors, hope that makes my intent clearer. Thanks!

[image: pointer diagram]

**The Question:**

Is there a way to create a reference from an existing reference? It feels like I should be able to make another pointer of `'a` lifetime and make it point to an object of `'a` liftime. Or are there better approaches to solving problems like this?

Answer (score 1):

`Vec` has a `retain` method which almost does what you want. It doesn't allow mutation of the elements before filtering them though. We can just write our own `retain_mut` method. I've just copied the code from immutable version and modified it to allow mutation.

```
trait RetainMut<T> {
    fn retain_mut(&mut self, f: |&mut T| -> bool);
}

impl<T> RetainMut<T> for Vec<T> {
    fn retain_mut(&mut self, f: |&mut T| -> bool) {
        let len = self.len();
        let mut del = 0u;
        {
            let v = self.as_mut_slice();
            for i in range(0u, len) {
                if !f(&mut v[i]) {
                    del += 1;
                } else if del > 0 {
                    v.swap(i-del, i);
                }
            }
        }
        if del > 0 {
            self.truncate(len - del);
        }
    }
}
```

And then your code looks like this

```
struct Result {
    val: int
}

struct Obj<'a> {
    all_results: Vec<Result>,
    current_results: Vec<&'a mut Result>
}

impl<'a> Obj<'a> {
    fn change_something (&mut self) -> &[&mut Result] {
        self.current_results.retain_mut(|result| {
            result.val += 1;
            result.val == 1
        });
        self.current_results.as_slice()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I was more looking for understanding than a solution, since I'm sure I'll be in a similar scenario in the future. Appreciate the single-pass solution though. I'll edit my question.